# Different types defined in variadic template class

Tags: templates, overloading, variadic

I'm trying to allow different users of these classes to pass different config to DoerT via a Monitor. If someone wants to use a "myU" they can, and if not they are not forced to pass one.  I then want to specialize a member function of DoerT for this particular NYConfig.   There are several "mains" to make this possible. I'm getting compiler errors:  EX:

```
Config.H

#include "Doer.H"

template<class T>
struct ConfigT
{
     typedef T myT;
     typedef DoerT<ConfigT> Doer;
};

template<class T, class U>
struct NYConfig
{
   typedef T myT;
   typedef U myU;
   typedef DoerT<NYConfig> Doer;
};




Monitor.H

#include "Config.H"
#include "Doer.H"

template<typename ...monitors>
struct Monitor;

template<class T>
struct Monitor<T>
{
   typedef ConfigT<T> Config;
   typedef DoerT<Config> Doer;
};

template<class T, class U>
struct Monitor<T,U>
{
  typedef NYConfig<T,U> Config;
  typedef DoerT<Config> Doer;
};


Doer.H

#include "Config.H"

template<class ConfigT>
class DoerT
{
    bool start();

};

template<class ConfigT>
bool DoerT<ConfigT>::start() {....}

//error is here:
//error 'NYConfig' was not declared in this scope.
//I've also tried <NYConfig<myT,myU> >::start
template<>
bool DoerT<NYConfig>::start() 
{
     if(NYConfig::u == "yes")
         return true;

     return false;
}




Main1.C

struct myT {int t; };
struct myU {std::string u};

typedef Monitor<myT,myU> monitor;
typedef monitor::Config Config;
static monitor m;

Main2.C
struct myT2 {int t2; }
typedef Monitor<myT2> monitor;
typedef monitor::Config Config;
static monitor m;
```

Comment: I might be missing something (I'm scanning as I'm about to have my tea!), but I don't think DoerT<NYConfig> would ever work because NYConfig is a template itself, so it can't appear unspecialised except if it's a template template parameter, which it isn't as you're specialising that function with the error. Also, aren't myT and myU defined inside NYConfig (and ConfigT)? Because if they are, you couldn't possibly pass them as template parameters to NYConfig.

Comment: EDIT: I now see that you define myU and myT at the end of the file, I missed this, but these can;t be used in the headers. I'm working on this, there are a few issues, but the error you see is due to a circular dependency issue, you include Doer.H in Config.H and vice versa.

Comment: Do you want Monitor always to use NYConfig if it is passed two parameters and ConfigT if passed one? Or is how many arguments are passed to Monitor a separate issue from whether to use ConfigT or NYConfig?